# Angular 2 - Displaying async Object data from promise

Tags: asynchronous, angular

Edit: It looks like my main problem now is that I can't seem to display async data from an object. I have a promise containing the data object, and when I use

```
{{ data | async }}
```

it will display

```
[object Object]
```

The issue is, I want to be able to display all the different attributes; i.e, Name, Symbol, etc. In Angular 1, I would just use

```
{{ data.Name | async }}
```

but that doesn't work here, since the async pipe tries to resolve the data.Name promise, which doesn't exist. I want to resolve the data promise and then display the Name key from it. At the moment, I'm working on creating my own pipe to display a key from an async object, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in Angular 2 pipe or function to handle this!

---

I've created a StockService class that returns a Promise containing an object to my StockInfo class, which contains the HTML to be displayed. I want to display the name of this object in my HTML, but I can't seem to get it to display.

In my StockInfo constructor:

```
this.stock.getStockData(this.ticker, http).then(function(val) {
  this.data = val;

  this.name = new Promise<string>(function(resolve) {
    resolve(this.data.Name);
  });
});
```

where this.stock is the StockService object.

In my HTML:

```
<h2>{{name | async}}</h2>
```

I've tried a number of different arrangements before settling on this one. I want the StockService class to handle the data fetching and the StockInfo class to handle the display. In Angular 1, I would create a factory for fetching data and handle the data processing in the controller, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this in Angular 2.

Is there a way to get it to display, or are there better ways to design my code that I should look into? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `{{ (data | async).Name }}` or `{{ (data | async)['Name'] }}` ?

Comment: Why do you make `this.name` into a promise instead of just writing `this.name = this.data.name`? Or is this just a contrived example?

Comment: @Pylinux I'd imagine it's a contrived example to allow for a [mcve].

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You do not need any special pipe. Angular 2 suppport optional field. You just need to add ? in your object

```
{{ (data | async)?.name }}
```

or

```
{{(name | async)?}}
```

Comment: Does `| async` work on promises? I thought it only worked on Observables?

Comment: `async` pipe accept either promise or observables. It's mention in the official Angular 2 documentation here. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: "The safe navigation operator `?` means that the field is optional and if undefined, the rest of the expression should be ignored" – from https://angular.io/cheatsheet

Answer (score 19):

There's nothing wrong with the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242764/1158189) above. But it becomes a hassle to append `| async?` when we need to display many properties of the object. The **more convenient solution** is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="data | async as localData">
   <div> {{ localData.name }} </div>
   <div> {{ localData.property1 }} </div>
   <div> {{ localData.property2 }} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be done without the conditional behavior of `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [pluck](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pluck.md) from [rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)/observable:

```
{{ user.pluck("name") | async }}
```

[Pluck](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pluck.md)
Returns an Observable containing the value of a specified nested property from all elements in the Observable sequence. If a property can't be resolved, it will return undefined for that value.

Comment: Those finding this in the future, note that "pluck" has been deprecated

Answer (score 4):

If you work with Observable you can display data like this way:

```
<div *ngIf="data | async; let _data">
   <h3>{{_data.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

or

```
<h3>{{(data | async).name}}</h3>
```

Comment: Please specify why this markup solves the problem, how it should be used and what mechanism makes it work. Considering linking some documentation.

Comment: I hope this helps you

Comment: What does _smth_ mean? Please prefer real words in your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making this too complex, and just need to do something like this.

```
this.name = 
  this.stock.getStockData(this.ticker, http)
  .then( val => val.Name )
```

and

```
<h2>{{name.Name | async}}</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks! This certainly makes things a lot simpler and I can't believe I didn't think to write it this way before, but the data still isn't displaying in the HTML. I've checked to make sure that getStockData is returning a Promise with the correct data, but I still can't get it to show up in the HTML.

Comment: are you certain that `getStockData` is calling `resolve`?

Comment: Yep; when I added a console.log to the monstrosity in my OP, the resulting value had all the data I wanted.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I change the HTML to <h2>{{name | async}}</h2>, it will display [object Object], but trying to dereference the Name key leads to nothing showing.

Comment: Thanks Simon! This works, but there are maybe 20 key-value pairs in this Object, and I want to display all 20 of these in the page. The getStockData method makes a HTTP GET request, and I want to be able to get all this data with a single call to getStockData. Is there no way to store the results in an object?

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up writing my own asynchronous key pipe. Huge thanks to Simon for helping guide me here.

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'key',
    pure: false
})

export class KeyPipe {
    private fetchedPromise: Promise<Object>;
    private result: string;

    transform(value: Promise<Object>, args: string[]) {
        if(!this.fetchedPromise) {
            this.fetchedPromise = value
                .then((obj) => this.result = obj[args[0]] );
        }
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<h2>{{ data | key: 'Name' }}</h2>
```

Someone please comment if Angular has its own functions for resolving a key from an asynchronous object.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked for promises but in case people are using `Observable`s, adapting @user2884505's answer, since `pluck` isn't directly available on observables as a method in recent versions of RxJS, you may have something like this :

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
  name: 'asyncKey',
  pure: false
})
export class AsyncKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private observable: Observable<Object>;
  private result: Object;

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {

    if (!this.observable) {
      this.observable = value.pipe(pluck(...args));
      this.observable.subscribe(r => this.result = r);
    }

    return this.result;
  }
}
```

And then, you can use it, even for nested keys :

```
{{ user$ | asyncKey: 'address' : 'street' }}
```