# Format date with angular2 moment

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular2-moment

I'm getting following error, when using `amTimeAgo` pipe from [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment).

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.
>      moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. 
>      Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. 
>      Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>      Arguments: 
>       [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 21-03-2017, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

Also pipe is printing `Invalid date`.

I'm using it like this:
    `<span class="date-created"> {{ job.createdAt | amTimeAgo }} </span>`

And value of `job.createdAt` is string in format: `22-03-2017`.

I understand that something is wrong with format, but don't know how to pass that custom format `('DD-MM-YYYY')` to pipe, so that `moment` package and this angular library can recognize it.

Any ideas?

Comment: A custom pipe for relative time is here. Have a look at this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528844/custom-pipe-filter-for-calculating-relative-time-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a new moment object to pass it into the pipe, like:

```
let newMomentObj = moment(job.createdAt, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

and in your html file:

```
<span class="date-created"> {{ newMomentObj | amTimeAgo }} </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess, the string is not being correctly converted to date.. you can try below two options:

```
{{job.createdAt |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy' | amTimeAgo }}
```

or convert the string to date in your typescript file:

```
let newDate = new Date(job.createdAt);
```

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work with pipe. I had to parse it using momentjs first. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

angular2-moment introduced from version [`1.4.0`](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140---2017-06-18) [`amParse`](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment#amparse-pipe) pipe that:

> Parses a custom-formatted date into a moment object that can be used with the other pipes

In your case, you can do something like the following:

```
<span class="date-created"> {{ job.createdAt | amParse:'DD-MM-YYYY' | amTimeAgo }} </span>
```

this way you can parse your date string directly in your view.