# RxJs with Angular2 Bindings not getting updated

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am new to Angular2 and Rx.

My intention is to get the users from Git hub and display login names. (I got the snippet when I was reading through RxJs online) I want to implement it using Angular 2.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  private listEmpty : boolean;
  private userList : any;
  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.listEmpty = true;
      this.userList = [];

      var reqStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');
      var responseStream = reqStream.flatMap(function(reqUrl){
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(reqUrl));
      });

      responseStream.subscribe((res)=>{
         this.userList = res;
         this.listEmpty = false;
      });

  }  
}
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="listEmpty">List empty</div>
<div *ngFor="let u of userList">
        <span>{{u.login}}</span>
</div>
```

Problem :
In the snippet:

```
responseStream.subscribe((res)=>{
             this.userList = res;
             this.listEmpty = false;
          });
```

Data is found in 'res' variable when I debugged in chrome console and the 
'subscribe' function body is getting executed.
But the changes are not getting reflected in the view.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Try doing `<div *ngFor="let u of (userList | async)?">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363161/angular-2-displaying-async-object-data-from-promise

Comment: Don't use jQuery to send HTTP request. Use the Http Angular service, which returns an Observable:  `http.get(url).map(resp -> resp.json()).subscribe(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular service for get the the data by http. Link here :- [Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)