# Angular 4: Bind once only to method which returns promises

Tags: angular, binding

I am new to Angular so please forgive me if I don;t use the correct terminology.

I am trying to create a table dynamically by binding the td data to a method call. Like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let rw of ParameterRowData" >
    <td *ngFor="let field of fields" class="lalign" [innerHTML]="getCellData(field, rw.ParameterData)" ></td>
    <td><a  >Edit</a> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am doing this because I won't know the avaliable columns and data until it's returned from the server. My problem is that the getCellData method is being called over and over and over. The browser freezes, but in the console, I can see that it is being called again and again up to infinity. I just want it to be called once.

the getCellData method is as follows:

```
getCellData(field: ParamField, fields : ParameterRowFieldContract[]) : Promise<string>
  {
        for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
        {           
            if(fields[i].Name===field.DisplayName)
            {
                console.log('a');
                if(field.DataType == "FOREIGNKEYLIST")
                {
                    //getforeign key value to display
                    console.log('b');
                    var value = this.paramService.getParameterDataWithId(field.ForeignParameter, fields[i].Value)
                    .then(para => {     
                        for(var k=0; k<para.ParameterData.length; k++)
                        {
                            console.log('c');
                            if(para.ParameterData[k].Name===field.ForeignField)
                            {
                                console.log('foreign ='+ para.ParameterData[k].Value);
                                return para.ParameterData[k].Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                    return value;

                }
                else
                {               
                    return Promise.resolve(fields[i].Value);
                }   
            }       
        }
  }
```

At the end of the day I just want to display the returned value from the service in the HTML td element. I am willing to go an alternative route to solve this problem. The data won't be edited once it is loaded into the table, but I am not sure if one-way binding can help me and I don't yet understand how to implement one-way or two-way binding.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: you need a good understanding of angular concepts before building such application.

Comment: That is true. But I've been thrown into the deep end. This is my chance to impress, so go no choice.

Comment: Perhaps a custom angular pipe could have been an easier solution? Like the last solution in this question : [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363161/angular-2-displaying-async-object-data-from-promise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround solution.

First of all I was binding to an expression that that returns a promise. At this link [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#avoid-side-effects), the angular team discourages the use of complex epressions here:

> The expression could call something like getFoo(). Only you know what getFoo() does. If getFoo() changes something and you happen to be binding to that something, you risk an unpleasant experience. Angular may or may not display the changed value. Angular may detect the change and throw a warning error. In general, stick to data properties and to methods that return values and do no more.

So to keep it simple, my method had to return a string.

As for the foreign data, I prefetched it on ngOnInit and stored it in a multidimensional (2D) array, foreigners.

```
foreigners = [];
foreignParamNames : string[];
```

Then in ngOnInit I fill it up with data. The foreignParamNames is to keep track of the index for the multi-demnsional array.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.foreigners = [];
this.foreignParamNames = [];
this.fields = this.param.Fields;
this.paramService.getParameterData(this.parameterName)
                 .then(
                   data => this.processData(data),
                   error =>  {console.log(error)});

var foren = this.fields.filter(a=> a.DataType == 'FOREIGNKEYLIST');
for(var i = 0; i< foren.length; i++)
{
    this.foreignParamNames.push(foren[i].DisplayName);
    this.foreigners.push([]);
}

for(var j =0; j< foren.length; j++)
{
    var that = this;
    var ogfield = foren[j];
    //get foreign field data
    this.paramService.getParameterData(foren[j].ForeignParameter)
                 .then(
                   foreignRows => {
                        var values : StringKeyValuePair[]
                        values =[];
                        for(var i=0; i<foreignRows.length; i++)
                        {
                            var foreignFields =  foreignRows[i].ParameterData;
                            var sk = new StringKeyValuePair();
                            for(var j =0; j<foreignFields.length; j++)
                            {   
                                if(foreignFields[j].Name=="Id")
                                {
                                    sk.Key = foreignFields[j].Value;
                                }
                                if(foreignFields[j].Name==ogfield.ForeignField)
                                {
                                    sk.Value = foreignFields[j].Value;
                                }           
                            }
                            values.push(sk);
                        }
                        var ii = that.foreignParamNames.indexOf(ogfield.DisplayName);
                        if(ii>=0)
                        {
                            that.foreigners[ii]=(values);
                        }
                   },
                   error =>  {console.log(error)});
    }
}
```

and then finally, the getCellData method no longer needs to fetch from the service, but can now fetch from the multi-dimensional array for its data. Here is the code.

```
getCellData(field: ParamField, fields : ParameterRowFieldContract[]) : 
string
{
    for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
    {           
        if(fields[i].Name==field.DisplayName)
        {

            if(field.DataType == "FOREIGNKEYLIST")
            {
                //getforeign key value to display                   
                var ii = this.foreignParamNames.indexOf(field.DisplayName);

                var foreignfields= <StringKeyValuePair[]>this.foreigners[ii];

                for(var k=0; k<foreignfields.length; k++)
                {
                    if(foreignfields[k].Key===fields[i].Value)
                    {
                        return foreignfields[k].Value;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {               
                return fields[i].Value;
            }   
        }       
    }
    return "N/A";
  }
```

The HTML template's code still stays the same. I hope this can help someone else who needs it. This is more like an alternative from my original line of thinking, but if anyone has a better way to do it, please feel free to assist